# How do I install the Don't Starve (Together?) "A New Reign" beta

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

A friend on steam told me there's (going to be?) a new expansion on Don't Starve (Together)? I'd love to start playing but am not sure how to install it.

Can anyone find/make a step by step guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the instructions to opt-in the beta at the [following link](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/69487-how-to-opt-in-to-a-new-reign-beta-for-dont-starve-together/) on the official forum.

Follow these instructions:

> - In steam click on Library > Games.
> - Scroll down to Don't Starve Together.
> - Right-click, select Properties.
> - Go to the BETAS tab.
> - In the dropdown, select the "anewreignbeta" branch.
> - In that same properties window, go to the Local Files tab and press  Verify Integrity Of Game Cache.
> - Your game will be updated to the beta version.
> - Run the game and go to Browse Games. You should see servers which are running the beta. Have fun!

At the link I've provided you can also find a visual guide with the steps highlighted.